# parse.com cloud code example doesn't compile

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Android Studio and following cloud code guide of parse.com: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

After deploying the first example which defines function "hello" on the cloud, I run below code in my Android project(I call the code in MainActivity:onCreate)

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new FunctionCallback<String>() {
    void done(String result, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // result is "Hello world!"
        }
    }
});
```

I get this error:

> Error:(29, 116) error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method done(String,ParseException) in FunctionCallback

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to add @override.
Mine is working with this code. Good luck!

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, object.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the cloud function via the below code;

```
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new FunctionCallback<String>() {
        public void done(String result, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                System.out.println("Result:"+result);
            }
        }

    });
```

Also ensure that use proper Cloud function name and your Parse application is initialized. Hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error!

After a while I've found out that I was importing the wrong ParseException class.

Android Studio auto import the class java.text.ParseException, when the correct one is com.parse.ParseException.

Just change the import and see if it works.